# How to change the powerpoint view type as Reading view programmatically?

Tags: c#, vba, powerpoint, office-interop, office-2010

There is a new view type introduced in powerpoint 2010 called as 'Reading View'. I am trying to apply it to a presentation but the PpViewType Enumeration of office interop does not contain any member that will modify the presentation view as 'Reading view'. could anybody help me whether it has defined somewhere else or how I can change to Reading view programmatically?

```
PowerPoint.Application oPPT = new PowerPoint.Application();

//Add New Presentation
PowerPoint.Presentations oPresSet = oPPT.Presentations;
PowerPoint.Presentation oPres = oPresSet.Add(Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue);

//Add Slides to the Presentation
PowerPoint.Slides oSlides = oPres.Slides;
PowerPoint.Slide oSlide = oSlides.Add(1, PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutTitleOnly);
oSlide.Shapes[1].TextFrame.TextRange.Text ="sample text";

//Changing View Type
oPres.Application.ActiveWindow.ViewType = PowerPoint.PpViewType.ppViewNotesPage;
```

Comment: C# or VBA ? can you show the code where you set the Viewtype so far? Are you sure if C#, you are referencing the correct version of the COM Office libraries / PIA, the 2010 I mean...

Comment: anything is fine. I am referencing office 14 version only. see here [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.ppviewtype.aspx) The code is simple.Edited the main post for the code

Comment: Wow Thanks man!! ActiveWindow.ViewType exactly what I was searching to convert Reading view to Normal view : )

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be able to switch to the Reading View from the object model directly but you can approximate it for read only presentation files in Office 2010+:

- Start a slide show with ShowType of ppShowTypeWindow2.
- Close the original DocumentWindow
- Mark the presentation as Saved.

VBA example

```
Dim pres As Presentation
Dim settings As SlideShowSettings

Set pres = ActivePresentation
Set settings = pres.SlideShowSettings

settings.ShowType = ppShowTypeWindow2
settings.Run

pres.Windows(1).Close
pres.Saved = msoTrue
```